# The interval $[a,b] \subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ and interval $[0,1] \subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic in their standard topologies.

Tags: general-topology

**Problem:** The interval $[a,b]$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ and interval $[0,1]$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic in their standard topologies.

**Definition of Homeomorphism:** We call the underlying bijection of a topological equivalence $h : X \to Y$ a homeomorphism. We say $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic.

**This is how I showed it.**

Let us define a function $f:[a,b]$$\to$$[0,1]$ by $f(x)$ = $\frac{x-a}{b-a}$, then we know that clearly $f(x)$ is well defined. Let, $f(x_1)$ = $f(x_2)$, then $\frac{x_1-a}{b-a}$ = $\frac{x_2-a}{b-a}$, therefore from that we get that $x_1-a$ = $x_2-a$ (when $b \neq a$). Therefore, $x_1$ = $x_2$. Thus, $f$ is injective or one-to-one. Let, $y$ $\in$ $[0,1]$ be any element and $f(x) = y$, then

$\implies \frac{x-a}{b-a}$ = $y$

$\implies x = (b-a)y + (x-a)$ = $a(1-y)+by$ $\in$ $[a,b]$. As, $[a,b]$ is a convex set, so each element in $[0,1]$ has a pre-image in $[a,b]$ as $a(1-y)+by$ is a pre-image of $y$. Now, clearly $f$ is surjective. Hence, it is bijective.

We now prove that $f$ is continuous. Let, $x_n$ be a sequence in $[a,b]$, such that $x_n \to x$. Then, we want to prove that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. Now, $f(x_n) = \frac{x_n-a}{b-a}$ $\to$ $\frac{x-a}{b-a}$ [Since, $x_n \to a$]. Therefore, we can see that, $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. Therefore, it is continuous.

Since, $[a,b]$ is a compact set (can I say it has standard (order) topology $b/c$ its sub-basis consists of positive and negative open rays or $(-\infty,a) \cup (b,\infty)$ ?) in standard topology, and also $[0,1]$ is $T_2$ in usual topology, we know that any continuous bijection from a compact space to a topological space is homeomorphism. Hence, $f$ is homeomorphism and $[a,b]$ and $[0,1]$ are homeomorphic. (Proved)

Please note my prof hasn't done compact sets so far so it will be a problem if I use that concept while proving it in class. Hence, it would be great if someone verifies my proof, helps me on notation and also explains me to show its homeomorphic without using compact set at the end.

Appreciate your continuous support. :)

Comment: Please use MathJax instead of pictures. In addition, I don’t see a question.

Comment: Example 4.12 is the question. You have to show that.

Comment: Example 4.12 is a statement not a question.

Comment: That's basically a question, it tells you to show that those are homeomorphic in their standard topologies.

Comment: It is not. It asserts that this is the case. An exercise would advise you to show this. Anyway, your question therefore is whether the assertion of the example is correct? Yes it is.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks

Comment: Just to add a minor point, you must assume that $a<b$. Otherwise the interval $[a,b]$ is the empty set and the statement is false.

Comment: @sampleuser or a singleton (e.g. $[3,3]=\{x: 3\le x\le 3\}=\{3\}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof basically does the following:

Define the map $f:[a,b]\to [0,1]: x\mapsto \frac{x-a}{b-a}$.

Then note that $f$ is bijective and we have (this follows from your surjectivity proof)

$f^{-1}: [0,1]\to [a,b]: x\mapsto a(1-x)+bx$.

Then you showed that $f$ is continuous using sequences but I'm not a fan of this argument. What you essentially used is that addition and scalar multiplication are continuous, so I recommend to use these facts to conclude instantly that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous. This also lets you avoid the compactness argument.

Also these sets are Hausdorff for the simple reason they are metrizable. No need to invent complex arguments involving the order topology.

Comment: So, I just have to show that $f$ and its inverse are continuous, then only I can reach conclusion. right?

Comment: Yes, you must find a continuous bijection $f$ such that $f^{-1}$ is continuous. The proposed map does exactly that.

Comment: alright, cool. So, this looks good, right? I thought maybe I did a mistake in my proof somewhere. but now i think its good. I just have to make minor changes and modify it and then I am done. Appreciate your help and time.

Comment: I didn't check every detail but the main strategy and techniques are definitely working.

Comment: great, sounds good. :)